# Run magento extension model inside php script

Tags: magento2, model, script, shell

I have a custom extension model like this:

**app/code/Namespace/Module/Model/Core.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model;
class Core
{
  public function save($data){
    ....
  }
}
```

I want to create a PHP script inside the same Magento project folder like this:

**script/test.php**

```
$model = \app\code\Namespace\Module\Model\Core; //roughly like this
$data = 'test';
$model->save($data);
```

is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$model = $objectManager->get('\Namespace\Module\Model\Core');
$data = 'test';
$model->save($data);
```

Comment: $model = $objectManager->get('\Namespace\Module\Model\Core');

Try to remove "\"

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code ................

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$searchItems = $objectManager->create('VendorName\Modulename\Model\Core')->functionName(); // functionName inside Core.php file
echo '<pre>';var_dump($searchItems);
```